# Search engine using url

Tags: javascript, php, html, search

I started making site for songs. It is lyrics site and I wanted a search engine that works something like picture below.

It should works with URL.

[image: Like this]

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="search"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
 require "connection-to.php";
  $notFound = "";
  $song = "";
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
  $search = strtolower($search);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `music` WHERE `name` = '" . $search . "'";
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
  if($numRows != 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row['lyrics'] . "<br><br><br>";
}
} else {
    echo $search . " Was Not Found.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure! What do you need help with? :) (You should probably read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I need help making search engine that works with URL like search?q=search+for+something @JimL

Comment: is your question "what the heck is a query string?" or "how can I make google?"

Comment: it's called a GET method. Search engine as in what; using text files and/or a db?

Comment: It is like Google but for my site only i found on Internet search engine that works with php but it doesn't add "?" to the URL @Federkun

Comment: I have already made a search engine that works with method get but it doesn't add "?" mark in URL it just shows you the result. I want the search engine that is showing you the result even if you made a mistake in spelling. Sorry my English is not so great. @Fred-ii-

Comment: you're going to have to post your code then; it's all guesswork for us

Comment: ok i will add  code above @Fred-ii-

Comment: 1/2 hour ago; answer posted. If you know how things roll on Stack, you'll know what to do, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want send a POST request. Change

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="" method="GET">
```

Then you can retrive it with `$_GET['search']` instead of `$_POST['search']`.

Comment: you should also replace `$_POST['submit']`. c'mon.

Comment: @Federkun: it will be good you update your answer with your comment above so as to make it complete.